# Specify Oracle Sequence in SimpleJdbcInsert object to generate key from Oracle Sequence

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, simplejdbcinsert, database-sequence

I am using SimpleJdbcInsert as,

```
SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName(TABLE_NAME).withSchemaName(SCHEMA_NAME);

Map<String, Object> namedParameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
namedParameterMap.put("ID", "MYSEQ.NEXTVAL");
namedParameterMap.put("COLUMN1NAME",obj1.getColumn1Value());
namedParameterMap.put("COLUMN2NAME", obj1.getColumn2Value());

simpleJdbcInsert.withoutTableColumnMetaDataAccess().execute(namedParameters);
```

But it throws error for ID column only , other columns work fine which I confirmed by commenting out the ID column.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

I checked my Oracle Sequence which is working correctly fine. I checked many blogs but could not find a proper blog which is using Oracle sequence with SimpleJdbcInsert.

Answer (score 2):

It is because jdbcTemplate tries to parse `"MYSEQ.NEXTVAL"` into a long, which is the datatype of `ID`. You can't send SQL statements as named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

---

we cannot use Oracle `sequence` in `SimpleJdbcInsert` directly. to do so we have to used `triggers` and insert sequence value dynamically.

my table name is

> **PRODUCT(ID,NAME,QTY,PRICE)**

1. create a database `sequence` (in my case its **PROD_ID**)
2. create a Database Trigger for getting PK value

> **CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROD_PK_GEN_TRIGGER 
>
> BEFORE INSERT ON PRODUCT
>
> FOR EACH ROW
>
> BEGIN
>
> SELECT PROD_SEQ.NEXTVAL
>
> INTO :new.ID
>
> FROM DUAL;
>
> END;**

3. use id as autogenerated key in java code

> ```
> SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = 
>      new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
>           .withTableName("PRODUCT")
>           .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID");
> ```

4. call `executeAndReturnKey()` method to execute and get the auto-generated key

   ```
         int  id  =  
            simpleJdbcInsert .executeAndReturnKey(
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(product))
                .intValue();
   ```

Note :: here by default `executeAndReturnKey()` method will return `java.lang.Number` type and to get pk in `int` type we must use `intValue()` method.